# Travis build error: sass requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0

Tags: rubygems, continuous-integration, travis-ci

So for some reason my Travis build is failed with the following error:

```
10.33s$ gem install sass
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.10.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.2
Fetching: ffi-1.9.18.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.18
Fetching: rb-inotify-0.9.10.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-inotify-0.9.10
Fetching: sass-listen-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-listen-4.0.0
Fetching: sass-3.5.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    sass requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
The command "gem install sass" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

```

My `travis.yml` file is as follows:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
    - 6
before_install:
    - gem install sass
    - gem install scss-lint
    - npm install -g grunt-cli 
install: 
    - npm install
before_script: 
    - grunt theme
```

```

I even tried specifying a Ruby version greater than 2, but the error of "sass requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0" still persists:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
    - 6
before_install:
    - gem update --system 2.1.11
    - gem --version
    - gem install sass
    - gem install scss-lint
    - npm install -g grunt-cli 
 install: 
    - npm install
before_script: 
    - grunt theme
```

I have another project with a more or less identical travis.yml file so can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I broke my build files with same kind of issue and after hours of searching i used rvm kind of thing to install ruby 2.0+ .

Comment: @ArpitSolanki thanks, I added `rvm install 2.2.4` to my `before_install` section and it worked.

Comment: posted an answer for future readers @EdmundReed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a package manager like [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to install ruby 2.0 and higher. Official ruby repositories installs v1.9 so that's why you are getting the error. The command below can be used for this.

```
rvm install 2.x
```